# How do Google, DeepL, Grammarly etc. make ML model predictions so fast?

Tags: python, performance, api

I want to build an API like Grammarly but the inference is way too slow, because I am using multiple Huggingface models and no matter what I do, they still remain slow. How do Grammarly, Google Translate, DeepL make their API inference so fast?

Answer (score 1):

something we need to think about is the power of computation and how thes big companies manage their configuration and their solutions, i don't know exactly how they make their model predictions so fast, but i find some good resources to study and understand a little bit better  The implementation of models ,

https://memotut.com/machine-learning-model-inference-web-api-server-configuration-fastapi-implementation-example-available-9803f/ ,
this part of the documentation, conteins really good information about the machine learning models and also their implementation

also there are some other really good resources like this page about good practice and also how to process request and manage Api's:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-implementation